# Fix ruby gems path issues in debian

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, debian

I've be banging my head against the wall trying to fix a ruby gems path without success. Here is my problem. In my production server running `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze)` I have both ruby1.8.7, ruby1.9.1 and jruby installed. For some reasons gem install uses jruby gems directory and not ruby gems directory which means I can not run ruby programs that depends on installed ruby gems. I've tried to export the ruby gem PATH using

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

but nothing changed.

Here is my `.bashrc` file

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'

JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/jdk1.6.0_21/
PATH="/usr/bin/jdk1.6.0_21/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:/opt/jruby/bin/"
export PATH
export GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Environment

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze)
Release:    6.0.6
Codename:   squeeze


gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-12-27 patchlevel 330) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/jruby/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/jruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.6
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/


which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

which gem
/opt/jruby/bin//gem
```

Here is the error I'm getting while running ruby file

```
usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- net/https (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I've been struggling to change that but with no luck. How do I change gem path on Debian?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a version manager like RVM/rbenv? They implement custom path modification.

Do you know which user you are running as and if you are using `sudo`? This can of course also have a huge impact on path interpretation.

Try this: navigate into the actual `Bin` folder of each of your Ruby implementations, and run the `gem env` command there. This has the effect running commands using that localized version of Ruby (and therefore RubyGems too in most cases). This can be very helpful in diagnosing these types of issues.

For example:

`cd /some_path/Ruby-1.9.1/bin`

`gem env`

Comment: I'm not using any version manager and I'm running as root user same when I run a ruby file. Navigating to /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin directory `gem env` give me the same results as shared in the post

Comment: Just a tip, running as root is usually not a good idea since when messing with Ruby paths, it can cause headache. Anyway, the path you suggested is not what I was referring to. It's the EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY, plain as day in your gem output there, so try `/opt/jruby/bin` as an example. Here is a random article that possibly would have useful info http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2845-installing-ruby-1-9-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-system/